# How to set Minimum Time in android TimePicker (not In TimePickerDialog)

Tags: android, android-timepicker

How can I set Minimum time in timepicker (I am not using TimePickerDialog). I have searched a lot but unable to find the correct answer. I am using TimePicker to get time from user. This is my xml Code

```
               <TimePicker
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:headerBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:id="@+id/timePicker" />
```

This is how I get in my code

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

Now how can I set minimum time to bound user not to select past time.

This is how my timepicker look like....I am not using TimePickerDialog because I have to show different stuff with time as we well. Thanks!

[image]